# When are GCHandles Created for Managed Objects Being Passed to Unmanaged Code?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, .net-internals

This is a question I had when I read the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962172/why-does-a-system-timers-timer-survive-gc-but-not-system-threading-timer). When exactly are GCHandles created for managed objects being passed into unmanaged code, and when are these handles freed?

An example where a GCHandle is created - alluded to in the link above but also verified with a memory profiling tool on my end - is within one of the methods called by the following overload of the System.Threading.Timer constructor:

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback, object state, int dueTime, int period)
```

One of the pathway for method calls is the following, read from top to bottom:

```
System.Threading.Timers.TimerSetup
System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimer
System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimerNative
```

I can see from my memory profiler that the System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimer method creates GCHandles, but I see no explicit call to GCHandle.Alloc in this method. Where is the GCHandle being created? Is it just an automatic thing that happens in .NET when a method leading to unmanaged code (in this case System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimerNative) is called?

Comment: P/Invoke marshalling shouldn't automatically allocate any GCHandles, since it cannot determine when to release them. Not sure about the method call trace you got there, since I do not find these classes in mscorlib. The one method that seems to interact with native code is `TimerQueue.ChangeAppDomainTimer`, which might do something regarding GCHandles internally.

Comment: To provide a bit more information, I am using the JetBrains dotPeek .NET decompiler to look at the implementation details of mscorlib (x86 and .NET Framework v3.5) from the GAC.