# CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested does not fire RequerySuggested

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm trying to test a class that uses `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` and noticed that calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` does not fire `RequerySuggested` from my test. Is there a reason for this and how to I resolve this issue? Does the `CommandManager` require some initialization?

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
[Test]
public void InvalidateRequerySuggested_TriggersRequerySuggested()
{
    bool triggered = false;
    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += (s, a) => triggered = true;

    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Just to be sure

    Assert.True(triggered); // Never true
}
```

Comment: Try converting the test into an Async test, I believe that you may need to return control to the `SynchronizationContext`, otherwise if you have 1000 RequerySuggested subscribers and 1000 InvalidateRequerySuggested, you would have a LOT of work on your hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx) under remarks, `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` only holds a weak event reference. In your unit test the lambda expression is being garbage collected.

Try the following:

```
bool triggered;
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => triggered = true;
CommandManager.RequerySuggested += handler;
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
GC.KeepAlive(handler);
Assert.IsTrue(triggered);
```

**Update**

From some further investigation, I believe I have pinpointed the problem.

`CommandManager.InvalidateRequestSuggested()` uses the current dispatcher to raise the event asynchronously.

Here is a solution:

```
bool triggered;
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => triggered = true;
CommandManager.RequerySuggested += handler;
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

// Ensure the invalidate is processed
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));

GC.KeepAlive(handler);
Assert.IsTrue(triggered);
```

Comment: The test still fails. And, as long as `handler != null`, `KeepAlive` is unnecessary - right?

Comment: The `KeepAlive` ensures the garbage collector does not collect `handler`. What I have pasted above would have definitely been a problem eventually (especially on memory starved systems). Your test must be failing for some other reason too though. I'll have a look into it in a bit :)

Comment: So `EventHandler handler` does not keep a strong reference to `(s, e) => triggered = true`?

Comment: It does, but the garbage collector is able to collect local variables which are no longer used or referenced. So in this case, after the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += handler;` line, `handler` is no longer used and is elligible for garbage collection thus the lambda is too.

Comment: As long as `handler` is not null I still can't see the need for `KeepAlive`. The reference in `CommandManager` is weak, but the local reference is strong?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409492/921321) for another explanation. It may be in a debug compilation, without optimizations, this is a non-issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include what I believe is the main problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason for this behaviour: I've found that we need to subscribe to the `RequerySuggested` event using the same Dispatcher as the one `InvalidateRequerySuggested` is called on.

I've created a few objects on a non-UI thread that subscribed to this event, and the event did not get raised. Changing

```
CommandManager.RequerySuggested += HandleRequerySuggestedSuggested;
```

to

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => 
    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += HandleRequerySuggestedSuggested));
```

solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a strong reference to your eventhandler